# Android - Saving Player data - Comparison of 3 different options

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

Welcome everyone!
I'm programming a mobile game on Anroid.
I really want to know how to save Player Data.
It will be a game that can be run on different devices without loss of data.

> 1. Using SharedPreferences
> 2. Using JSONObject, JSONArray and save it into file in Internal Storage and upload it to the external server
> 3. SQLite, MySQL

What would you choose? What are the pros and cons of each option?

I would like to save data for example:

> 1. Highscore
> 2. Life
> 3. Mana
> 4. Count of steps
> 5. Level of character
> 6. Amount of money
> 7. and more...

Comment: I feel it would be beneficial to explain more about the player data to empower people to provide you with a better, more tailored answer.

Comment: I edited a question. look up.

Comment: All of that information can just be included in the Player object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences should be the way to go for such a small amount of data. There are many benefits to using them over SQLite in this example.

I would discourage using external server because I personally would not like my game to require internet for playing.

Comment: But app requie internet acces for register/login player. External server is like back-up server.

Comment: in that case you can use it, but not rely on that. Use external server for some kind of backups, so users can switch to a different device and transfer progress, but also be sure to save a copy locally with SharedPrefs because it is bad user experience to not be able to play the game without internet connection.

Comment: Yea, I know it :) so do you prefer SharedPreferences, yes? For example, I log in into my app and some data is downloading from server. I put this data into SharedPreferences file and I can operate on it through all app?

Comment: Surely. They're quite easy to use and you can actually save a lot of primitive data (like what you said, high scores, progress, coins, whatever) in it.

Comment: In external server I need to create other table for user data or I can operate on existing table but I need to add some new columns like. progress, highscore etc.?

Comment: You can do that either way I guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much player data there will be.  But unless there is a lot of player data, I would suggest using shared preferences, especially if there is something simple like a Player object, or a list of Player objects. that will cover it.

You could use something like the following for a list of Players, and change any reference to that list to just a Player object if you only want to save 1.  If you have a lot of data, players, or would need extra security you may want to go with SQLLite.

```
public class PlayerPrefs {

    private static final String PLAYERS_PREF_FILE = "PLAYERS_PREF_FILE";
    private static final String PLAYERS = "PLAYERS";

    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(){
        final Context context = ApplicationData.getAppContext();
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PLAYERS_PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static List<Player> getPlayers() {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>() {}.getType();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs();
        String players = prefs.getString(PLAYERS, null);
        if (players == null){
            return new ArrayList<Player>();
        }
        return gson.fromJson(players, listType);
    }

    public static void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (players != null) {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = getPrefs();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(PLAYERS, gson.toJson(players));
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to include the following in your Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
```

Comment: It will be no multiplayer game, for now. One player - one device. I would liek to save data external because if I played game on my smartphone and now I want to play on ma tablet, data must be downloaded from external server.

Comment: Then this is a completely different question.  If you want it loaded externally and accessible from a centralized location you'll need web services set up on a server with at least a get and set service for the Player object.

Comment: But for the time being until you get that set up, to maintain that player data across sessions, I suggest you use the solution I have up there.

Comment: I have external service on the server which is communicating with client application through PHP scripts. I have one table 'users' which contains player data